# Encriptar texto en PSeInt

Tags: funciones, pseint

El programa tiene que encriptar una frase que el usuario ingresa vía teclado. 
Por ejemplo: Si se ingresa Hola como frase y 8 como clave el programa debería devolver Encriptado: IIIH

El problema es que no se muestra resultado en la pantalla.

```
SubProceso tado <- ascii ( Frase, clave)
    Definir CodLet, g Como Cadenas;
    CodLet <- "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    Definir i, j, k, L Como Enteros;
    clave <- 0;
    Frase <- "";
    k <-0;
    Definir tado Como Cadena;
    tado <- "";
    Para i<-1 Hasta longitud(Frase) Con Paso 1 Hacer
        g<-SubCadena(Frase, i, i);
        Para j<-1 Hasta 26 Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Si g=SubCadena(Codlet, j, j) Entonces
                k<-j;
            FinSi
        FinPara
        L<-(k+clave) % 27;
        tado <-concatenar(tado,subcadena(CodLet, L, L));
    FinPara
FinSubProceso

Proceso sin_titulo
    Definir Frase Como Cadena;
    Definir clave Como Entero;
    Leer Frase;
    Leer Clave;
    Escribir ascii(Frase,Clave);
FinProceso
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacía rato que no veía PSeInt jaja

Primeramente, tienes un error aquí:

```
clave <- 0;
Frase <- "";
```

Estás anulando los valores que pasas al llamar la función desde el proceso, haciendo que nunca entre en los Para.

Y...no creo que si ingrese "Hola" te devuelva "IIIH" puesto que las comparaciones las realizas sobre CodLet que sólo tiene mayúsculas, por lo que a lo mucho, al ingresar "Hola" sólo, por cómo veo que está hecho, te repetiría el valor de encriptado para 'H' 4 veces. Tendrías que incluir minúsculas en otro CodLet o al menos hacer que compare 'g' con mayúsculas y minúsculas.

La parte que te marqué como error tendrías que borrarla del código, porque no te deja hacer nada de lo otro.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Programa corregido

```
SubProceso tado <- ascii ( Frase, clave)
    Definir CodLet, g Como Cadenas;
    CodLet <- "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    Definir i, j, k, L Como Enteros;
    k <- 0;
    Definir tado Como Caracter;
    tado <- "";
    Para i<-0 Hasta longitud(Frase)-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        g<-SubCadena(Frase, i+1, i+1);
        Para j<-0 Hasta 26 Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Si g=SubCadena(Codlet, j, j) Entonces
                k<-j;
            FinSi
        FinPara
        L<-(k+clave) % 27;
        tado <-concatenar(tado,subcadena(CodLet, L, L));
    FinPara
FinSubProceso

Proceso sin_titulo
    Definir Frase Como Caracter;
    Definir clave Como Entero;
    Leer Frase;
    Leer clave;
    Escribir "Encriptado: ", ascii(Frase,Clave);
FinProceso
```